# Angular 2, different popups type

Tags: angular, typescript, popup, components

I've got some troubles while implementing popups in my angular 2 project. I've got 1 page where I need to place 10 different actions, clicking on them should show popup in which I can provide some more information or simple confirmation. The problem is that, there will be at least 5 diferent types of popups (one with date picker, 2 with dropdown menu, one with multiple dropdown menus etc.) I think that i'll need to implement different components(for every type of popup) and some dialog service. Does anyone knows how to do this with angular 2 good practices?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview would allow to display different components in an overlay container

Comment: Another approach could be, just provide general overlay design like header, body and footer with the customization flag and leave the implementation to the parent component using ng-content

Comment: @RRForUI Yeah, I think it's best solution in this issue.

Answer (score -1):

[PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) has `p-dialog` Overlay component

```
<p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="display">
    Content
</p-dialog>
```

Will prefer 5 different types of component implementation if business is complex. and use selectors in place of `Content` section of `p-dialog`

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I dont like the prime-ng approach personally